# Exporting Table in SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, export

I am using the following SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FullExport]
(
@db_name as nvarchar(100),
@table_name varchar(100),   
@file_name  varchar(100)
)
as
Begin
//Generate column names as a recordset
DECLARE @columns varchar(8000), @sql varchar(8000), @data_file varchar(100)

SELECT @columns=coalesce(@columns+',','')+column_name+' as '+column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name=@table_name

SELECT @columns=''''''+replace(replace(@columns,' as ',''''' as '),',',',''''')

//Create a dummy file to have actual data
SELECT @data_file = substring(@file_name,1,len(@file_name)-    
charindex('\',reverse(@file_name)))+'\data_file.xls'

//Generate column names in the passed EXCEL file
SET @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp " SELECT * FROM
(SELECT '+ @columns+') as t"    queryout "'+@file_name+'" -c'''

exec(@sql)

//Generate data in the dummy file
SET @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT * from '+@db_name+'..'  
+@table_name+'"   queryout "'+@data_file+'" -c'''

exec(@sql)

//Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file
SET @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "' +
@file_name+'"'''

exec(@sql)

//Delete dummy file 
SET @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''

exec(@sql)
```

END

The file is being created but the content is empty , any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start you should delimit your column names as [name with included space], but I'd be inclined to find if the dummy file is zero length first, then run the query generated in SQL Management Studio to find what rows it returns (if any) and what error messages it gives